# toolbar with content in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a Toolbar on the page. I'm going to display content on the same page with the click on the items in the toolbar. How can the Toolbar in Ionics display content?

```
<ion-toolbar no-border-top>
<ion-segment>
  <ion-segment-button value="input">
    title1
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="output">
    title2
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="internal">
     title3
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="external">
    title4
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: Hello! can we have a bit more precisions? It's not clear if you are trying to display content inside the `toolbar` element, or want it to interact with your page's content part. Also, what have you tried and why it didn't fit your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the click events of the ion-segment-buttons like

```
<ion-toolbar no-border-top>
<ion-segment>
  <ion-segment-button value="input" (click)="alterContent()">
    title1
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="output">
    title2
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="internal">
    title3
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="external">
    title4
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

in ts-file

```
alterContent(){
  this.content = "anotherContent";
}
```

where content is displayed in the content area of your page like

```
<ion-content>
  {{content}}
</ion-content>
```

But when you want to change the complete content of the page there are tabs to archive this. See [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs) for details.